# Django: Join Two Models without ForeignKey: (Can i Use Polymorphic Relation, if Yes Then How)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Services(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    medical_unit = models.ForeignKey(MedicalUnits, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='services_medical_unit',
                                     blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    billing_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    department_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    assignable_type = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    assignable_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    department_service_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    ward_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'services'

class PackageServices(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    billing_package = models.ForeignKey(BillingPackages, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    assignable_type = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    assignable_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'package_services'
```

I want To access "PackageService" Through "Services".

Comment: How are these 2 models related? I don't see a relationship field between them.

Comment: Is there a reason you set id? If many-to-one doesn't suit there are Many-to-Many and One-to-Ones https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/